# Preserve newlines on user selected text. Currently trying with window.getSelection()

Tags: tostring, multiline, getselection

```
cl_in = window.getSelection().toString();
alert(cl_out);  //Multiline selections stored without \r or \n
```

---

Input:
    "Hello,
Message,
Thanks"

Current output:
    "Hello,Message,Thanks".

My requirement is to be able to select some text on screen which contains line breaks, and store the data with the line break information for parsing.
I don't need to maintain formatting or any specific elements. Just pure text selection with multiline support.

I don't care if the linebreaks need to be replaced with a different character to be stored in the string. Or if the string needs to be broken up into an array. Any possible solution which allows me to maintain the linebreak data is fine.

getSelection().toString() does not seem to be saving any \r or \n information.

edit: In case it is relevant this is javascript in greasemonkey.

Thank you.

Comment: Any chance I can get a reply on this?
I did a lot of searching to ensure the issue had not been previously covered.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across a similar problem was able to solve it by using regex to replace the newlines with breaks.
`.replace( /(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>' );`
And using `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` when inserting the content into the dom

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out just now just in case anyone else is still wondering: you need to use a `textarea` element instead of a div or input element in order to have newlines be preserved when copying.